# Remove text which is in double quotes in a string

Tags: javascript, power-automate

I have an issue with power automate flow.
I have an string where I want to remove any text which is in double quotes and replace it with blanc value.

Example:

```
This is a string "with" blabla.
```

Change in to:

```
This is a string blabla.
```

I have tried to use replace function but failed because I don't know the regex.
This doesn't work:

```
replace('This is a string "with" blabla.','"?*','')
```

tried to with
replace('This is a string "with" blabla.','/(".+?")/gm','')

Comment: What about the regex `/(".+?")/gm`?

Comment: Your replace is not syntactically correct